# How to give the appearance of a button with a <div>?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking at the buttons used on twitter's home page, specifically the big orange 'signup' button. I see it is defined like this:

```
<p id="signup-btn">
    <a id="signup_submit" href="/signup">
        <span>Sign Up</span>
    </a>
</p>
```

are they just using css to give the orange button appearance (which may just be a jpg), and also using css to specify the roll-over appearance (another jpg), and finally a third state for mouse-click (another jpg) to give the impression of a real clickable button?

If that's how it works, what should I look for to do the same thing? In my case I just want to make a  button I guess, like:

```
<div class='mybutton'>Hello!</div>
.mybutton {
   bgcolor: red;
   bgcolor-mouseover: yellow;
   bgcolor-mousedown: green;
}
```

yeah something like that would be great,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at their CSS:

```
background: #FA2 url(http://s.twimg.com/a/1275412898/images/fronts/bg-btn-signup.png) repeat-x 0px 0px;
border: 1px solid #FA2;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
color: #333;
display: block;
font: normal normal bold 18px/normal Arial, sans-serif;
padding: 8px 10px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: #FE6 0px 1px 0px;
```

Comment: This is anti-semantic markup. A div should be a container, not a button. That's what the `<button>` element is for.

Comment: Except anyone browsing with javascript or CSS disabled, or using a screen reader. How would they know they have to click on the invisible box that looks like normal text? Not to mention anyone who could be editing your code in the future knows where you live.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't looked at it specifically, but that is entirely possible with CSS; they probably have a named style using the #signup-btn designation in CSS.  To find out, you can use IE or FireFox with FireBug to examine the CSS and see exactly what they do for the button style.  I would highly recommend that.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [BUTTON](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) element and [CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites). That way, you can style it however you like, and don't have to screw around with click() events in JS. Just use it wherever you'd use a regular button in a form.

**EDIT**: Coronatus, you should probably read this: [Rediscovering the Button Element](http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/). They're remarkably easy to make visually consistent across browsers using a little CSS.

Comment: Sorry but -1. Styling a button consistently across browsers is almost impossible, and you want to make it harder using background images? Good luck...